# Rails-Attach file using multiple controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to Rails. I have a Posts, Comments, and Attachments controller. I made my own Attachments controller since I am using the FilePicker API. I am trying to build it so that a user can attach a file to a post as well as attach a file to a comment if they wish.

Posts Controller

```
def create
    @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)

    if @post.save
        flash[:success] = "Your post has been created!"
        redirect_to root_path
    else
        flash[:alert] = "Your new post couldn't be created!  Please check the form."
        render :new
    end
end
...
private

  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:caption, :user_id)
  end
```

Attachments Controller

```
def create
    title = params[:attachment][:title]

    if Attachment.exists?(:title => title)
        redirect_to attachments_path
    else
        @attachment = current_user.attachments.build(attachment_params)
        @attachment.user_id = current_user.id
        name = params[:attachment][:name]
        @attachment.save
        redirect_to attachments_path
    end

end
...
private

    def attachment_params
        params.require(:attachment).permit(:title, :user_id, :name)
    end
```

Posts View for submitting a post

```
<%= simple_form_for(@post) do |f| %>

 <div class="profile_container">
    <div class="updateArea">

        <%= f.text_area :caption, class: "textarea", placeholder: "Post here", label: false %>

        <%= f.button :submit, "Post", disabled: true, class: "post_button", id: "post_button_padding" %>

        <%# <%= f.association :user %>
    </div>
</div>
```

Attachments view to upload a file

```
<%= filepicker_js_include_tag %>

<%= simple_form_for @attachment, :html=> { id: 'file_stack_form' } do |f| %>

<%= f.filepicker_field :title, multiple: 'false', onchange: 'onUpload(event)', services: "CONVERT, BOX, COMPUTER, DROPBOX, EVERNOTE, FACEBOOK, GMAIL, IMAGE_SEARCH, FLICKR, GITHUB, GOOGLE_DRIVE, SKYDRIVE, URL, WEBCAM, INSTAGRAM, VIDEO, AUDIO, CLOUDDRIVE, IMGUR" %>
<%= f.submit %>

<% end %>
```

routes.rb

```
resources :posts do
    resources :comments
end

resources :attachments
```

So I have comments attached to posts and created that association via nested routes and the associations between the models via has_many and belongs_to. Now would I need to do the same for Attachments or is there another method? I want a relationship between Posts/Comments and Attachments so that a user can attach files, but I will also have a separate section in my app to purely upload/download files with no need for a "post", which is why I have a separate controller for attachments. Any advice on how to build this functionality so a user can attach a file to their post would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend splitting attachments as you see them into two separate entities.  I would say post_attachments belong_to posts/comments and then I would make a second model entity called something like direct_upload that doesn't get associated with posts/comments at all and handles the direct upload/download situation you mentioned.  This will make it easier for you to maintain since you're already rolling your own file attachments and if anyone ever collaborates with you it will be move clear as to what is expected from each model class.

Comment: I was thinking of doing the same just to keep it clean as you suggested. Any advice on how I would integrate the current Attachments model I have with the posts model?